# How can I restore "chrome://plugins" to default settings?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

In `chrome://plugins`, I've messed around by enabling/disabling some plugins. Now I want them back to the "default" state.

Is there any way I could do that?

For me, *Chrome NaCl / DivX VOD Helper Plug-in - Version: 1.0.0.403* is disabled, but I forgot what its default value was. The same goes for a couple of others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fresh Google Chrome 11.0.696.71 profile on Mac OS X contains:

- Flash (enabled)
- QuickTime (enabled)
- Java (enabled)
- Chrome PDF Viewer (enabled)
- Chrome NaCl (**disabled**)
- Default Plug-In (enabled)

It looks like everything except NaCl is enabled by default.

---

To find out the definitive defaults for your configuration, just move the Google Chrome profile data temporarily, or launch Chrome on a user account that hasn't used it before (e.g. a newly created one if you have to).